# Getting positions from Python lists to generate a dynamic range

Tags: python, list

I have a list being built in Python, using this code:

```
def return_hosts():
    'return a list of host names'
    with open('./tfhosts') as hosts:
        return [host.split()[1].strip() for host in hosts]
```

The format of *tfhosts* is that of a hosts file, so what I am doing is taking the hostname portion and populating that into a template, so far this works.

What I am trying to do is make sure that even if more hosts are added they're put into a default section as the other host sections are fixed, this part however I would like to be dynamic, to do that I've got the following:

```
rendered_inventory = inventory_template.render({
        'host_main': gethosts[0],
        'host_master1': gethosts[1],
        'host_master2': gethosts[2],
        'host_spring': gethosts[3],
        'host_default': gethosts[4:],
})
```

Everything is rendered properly except the last host under the host_default section, instead of getting a newline separated lists of hosts, like this (which is what I want):

```
[host_default]
dc01-worker-02
dc01-worker-03
```

It just write out the remaining hostnames in a single list, as (which I don't want):

```
[host_default]
['dc01-worker-02', 'dc01-worker-03']
```

I've tried to wrap the host default section and split it, but I get a runtime error if I try:

```
[gethosts[4:].split(",").strip()...
```

Comment: what is `inventory_template.render()` function?

Comment: It's using Jinja and looks like this:

`inventory_template = jinja2.Template(inventory)

rendered_inventory = inventory_template.render({
        'host_main': gethosts[0],
        'host_master1': gethosts[1],
        'host_master2': gethosts[2],
        'host_spring': gethosts[3],
        'host_default': gethosts[4:],
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `gethosts[4:]` returns a list, if `gethosts` is a list (which seems to be the case) , hence it is directly writing the list to your file.

Also, you cannot do `.split()` on a list (I guess you hoped to do `.split` on the string, but `gethosts[4:]` returns a list). I believe an easy way out for you would be to join the strings in the list using `str.join` with `\n` as the delimiter. Example -

```
rendered_inventory = inventory_template.render({
    'host_main': gethosts[0],
    'host_master1': gethosts[1],
    'host_master2': gethosts[2],
    'host_spring': gethosts[3],
    'host_default': '\n'.join(gethosts[4:]),
})
```

Demo -

```
>>> lst = ['dc01-worker-02', 'dc01-worker-03']
>>> print('\n'.join(lst))
dc01-worker-02
dc01-worker-03
```

---

If you own the template, a cleaner approach would be to loop through the list for `host_default` and print each element in the template. Example you can try using a [`for` loop construct in the jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for-loop).

Comment: Brilliant, that does exactly what I was looking for.